# Work with a persistent object in a for loop F#

Tags: f#, roslyn

I'm trying to use Roslyn objects within F#. I don't know how to modify a object in a loop.

ClassDeclarationSyntax has an persistent API. Each time the object is modified it returns a new object. I'm not sure how to use this in F#.

```
let addPublicProperties (cls: ClassDeclarationSyntax) (props: Map<string, string>)=
for KeyValue(k, v) in props do
    (cls.AddMembers(SyntaxFactory.PropertyDeclaration(SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName(k), v)
            .AddModifiers(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword))))
cls
```

Looks like fold is the key to make this work

```
let addPublicProperties (cls: ClassDeclarationSyntax) (props: Map<string, string>)=
    Map.fold (fun (state:ClassDeclarationSyntax) key (value:string) -> 
       (state.AddMembers(SyntaxFactory.PropertyDeclaration(SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName(key), value)
            .AddModifiers(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword))))) cls props
```

Comment: I can't read F# so I don't know what you're doing. However, since everything in Roslyn is immutable you have to re-assign a modified object. I don't know if you're doing that there.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel That's exactly what fold seems to do. At the end the class has all the properties from the props map. It looks like the function return is assigned to the state for each element in the map.

Answer (score 0):

Just a stab in the dark.

```
let addPublicProperties (cls: ClassDeclarationSyntax) (props: Map<string, string>)=
    props |> Seq.iter (fun (k,v) -> 
        cls.AddMembers(SyntaxFactory.PropertyDeclaration(SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName(k), v)
            .AddModifiers(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword))) |> ignore)
    cls
```

If this does not work, try a replacing `(k,v)` with with `KeyValue(k,v)`.

Comment: yes. I do. i'm going for a fluentish API. Also the example you've sent. Doesn't quite compile.

Comment: F# isn't a big on fluentish API's. Instead, you should consider a piping paradigm.

Comment: That's why I want it to return a class. So I could pipe it into the next function that accepts classes. And also KeyValue doesn't help.

Comment: Also iter won't work because cls.AddMembers returns a new Object. It complains that it doesn't return unit.

Comment: It looks like what i'm looking for is Map.fold. Will give it a try.

Comment: The fold seems to be doing what I want. Please see the updated question. You could update your answer and I could accept it. Since I cannot accept my own answers.

Comment: @6D65, you should make your answer an answer anyway, instead of putting it in the question. Are you sure you can't accept your own answers? I think you can after a few days.

Comment: @Benjol as far as I remember there's a check box when creating a question asking whether I want to be able to answer my own question. I always leave that unticked. That being said. There's a button at the bottom with the title "Answer You Question". Will give that a try.

Comment: Thank you @GuyCoder. I've been on SO for years. Haven't had to use this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Map.fold seems to have the behaviour i'm looking for. It loops through the props map values. And passes and additional argument to the lambda(I named it state, as per example in the documentation). This state is passed each time the lambda is called. And judging by the result, the return value from the lambda becomes the state.

```
let addPublicProperties (cls: ClassDeclarationSyntax) (props: Map<string, string>)=
   Map.fold (fun (state:ClassDeclarationSyntax) key (value:string) -> 
      (state.AddMembers(SyntaxFactory.PropertyDeclaration(SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName(key), value)
        .AddModifiers(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword))))) cls props
```